# How to represent existing data as std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, adapter, placement-new

I have to pass existing data (`unsigned char` memory area with known size) to the library function expecting `const std::vector<std::byte>&` . Is there any way to "fool" the library function to believe that it received a vector while operating on existing data?

1. I have data from the old legacy as a pointer and size, not as a `std::vector`. Legacy C code allocates memory by malloc() and provides pointer and size. Please do not suggest touching the legacy code - by the end of the phrase I'll cease to be an employee of the company.
2. I don't want to create temporary vector and copy data because memory  throughtput is huge (> 5GB/sec).
3. Placement new creates vector - but with the first bytes used for the vector data itself. I cannot use few bytes before the memory area - legacy code didn't expect that (see above - memory area is allocated by malloc()).
4. Changing third party library is out of question. It expects const std::vectorstd::byte& - not span iterators etc.

It looks that I have no way but to go with temporary vector but maybe there are other ideas... I wouldn't care but it is about intensive video processing and there will be a lot of data to copy for nothing.

Comment: Nope, there's no fooling in C++. If an object demands a vector, it can only receive a vector, no foolin'. There is no way to create a vector referencing data that it does not own. And even placement new won't do anything, in this situation, either.

Comment: which library function is it? If it took iterators it would be possible

Comment: I dont understand why you consider 3 as an option. If thats a viable option then why not using a `std::vector<byte>` and for the raw array use its `data()` ?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no `std::vector<T>(T[], size_t);` that moves a C array into a vector. Not sure why not, seems like that should be useful.

Comment: Can't you create a vector at the start and have the legacy code work on `vector.data()`?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow because `std::vector<T>` is actually `std::vector<T, std::allocator<T>>`, and in general the allocator doesn't free the array properly

Comment: Does the legacy code deal with the ownership of the existing data, or does it receive a buffer to fill?

Comment: @Caleth If the array was allocated by new then I think the default new/delete allocator would work. For malloc/free you would need to supply your own allocator. There already is a memory resource for using an array on the stack as memory. Making one for memory on the heap should be a trivial change to that.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow yes, but the allocator is part of the type of the vector. So you still can't wrap an automatic storage array in a `std::vector<T>`. And we now have something that represents a non-owning view: `std::span<T>`

Comment: Petition the library vendor to include an iterator based function or a std::span<std::byte> version.

Comment: @Caleth They really screwed that part up when they added allocators. Luckily that part got better with the polymorphic allocator. Libraries should support `std::pmr::vector`.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Or you could use owning thing for ownership, and non-owning things in non-owning situations. Defaulting to `pmr` is a massive pessimisation if you only ever use `std::allocator`

Comment: @Caleth But the one time you use something else the benefits can be massive. Like 5-20 time speedup easily.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to "fool" the library function to believe that it received a vector while operating on existing data?

No.

The potential options are:

1. Put the data in a vector in the first place.
2. Or change the function expecting a vector to not expect a vector.
3. Or create a vector and copy the data.

If 1. and 2. are not valid options for you, that leaves you with 3. whether you want it or not.

Answer (score 1):

As the top answer mentions, this is impossible to do in standard C++. And you should not try to do it.

If you can tolerate only using libstdc++ and getting potentially stuck with a specific standard library version, it looks like you can do it. Again, you should not do this. I'm only writing this answer as it seems to be possible without UB in this specific circumstance.

It appears that the current version of libstdc++ exposes their vectors' important members as `protected`: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_vector.h#L422

All you need to do is inherit from `std::vector` (it's not forbidden), write your own constructor for setting these protected members, and write a destructor to reset the members so that the actual vector destructor does not delete your memory.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>

template <class T>
struct dont_use_me_in_prod : std::vector<T>
{
    dont_use_me_in_prod(T* data, size_t n) {
        this->_M_impl._M_start = data;
        this->_M_impl._M_finish = data + n;
        this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage = this->_M_impl._M_finish;
    }  

    ~dont_use_me_in_prod() {
        this->_M_impl._M_start = nullptr;
        this->_M_impl._M_finish = nullptr;
        this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage = nullptr;
    }
};

void innocent_function(const std::vector<int>& v);

void please_dont_do_this_in_prod(int* vals, int n) {
    dont_use_me_in_prod evil_vector(vals, n);
    innocent_function(evil_vector);
}
```

Note that this is **not** compiler, but standard library dependent, meaning that it'll work with clang as well as long as you use libstdc++ with it. But this is not conforming, so you gotta fix `innocent_function` somehow soon:
https://godbolt.org/z/Tfcn7rdKq

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `std::vector` is not a reference class like `std::string_view` or `std::span`. `std::vector` owns the managed memory. It allocates the memory and releases the owned memory. It is not designed to acquire the external buffer and release the managed buffer.

What you can do is a very dirty hack. You can create new structure with **exactly the same layout** as a `std::vector`, assign the data and size fields with what you get from external lib, and then pass this struct as a `std::vector const&` using `reinterpret_cast`. It can work as your library does not modify the vector (I assume they do not perform `const_cast` on `std::vector const&`).

The drawback is that code is unmaintainable. The next STL update can cause application crash, if the layout of the `std::vector` is changed.

Following is a pseudo code

```cpp
struct FakeVector
{
  std::byte* Data;
  std::size Size;
  std::size Capacity;
}; 

void onNewData(std::byte* ptr, size_t size)
{
  auto vectorRef = FakeVector{ptr, size, size};
  doSomething(*reinterpret_cast<std::vector<std::byte>*>(&vectorRef)); 
}
```

Comment: This has undefined behaviour. You can't alias unrelated types

Comment: @Caleth The topic starter has explicit task, which he explained clearly. You either do business and earn money or you are getting out of business. You care about C++ correctness, while C++ is just an instrument. I believe the solution I posted makes sense in short term and in long term, yes, they should think about refactoring.

Comment: The thing about undefined behaviour is that it *doesn't* have to immediately break. Are you going to notice that doing this subtly corrupted some other part of the processes address space?

Comment: @Caleth at the end you deal with CPU registers and raw memory. If you implement that hack carefully (actually you can just copy-paste the implementation of the std::vector and modify it) so the ASM code for both `std::vector` and `FakeVector` is **identical**, you don't wanna get UB in the nearest future.

Comment: No, `*reinterpret_cast<std::vector<std::byte>*>(&vectorRef))` has undefined behaviour for any `struct VectorRef`, no matter it's layout. *As far as you can tell*, your *current implementation* chooses to implement *what you think should happen*, purely by chance.

Comment: @DmytroOvdiienko, if you are writing C++ code, you are not dealing with CPU registers and raw memory, you are dealing with the C++ abstract machine.

Comment: @FatihBAKIR I mean when code is compiled, you get native CPU instructions. Two executables which have exactly the same binary code, given an input produce exactly the same output (that is a property of the "algorithm" term). As long as `FakeVector` produces the same CPU instructions as a `std::vector`, you are safe.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found the way working for me. I must admit that it is not fully standard compliant because casting of vector results in undefined behavior but for the foreseeable future I wouldn't expect this to fail. Idea is to use my own Allocator for the vector that accepts the buffer from the legacy code and works on it. The problem is that `std::vector<std::byte>` calls default initialization on resize() that zeroes the buffer. If there is a way to disable that - it would be a perfect solution but I have not found... So here the ugly cast comes - from the `std::vector<InnerType>` where InnerType is nothing but std::byte with default constructor disabled to the `std::vector<std::byte>` that library expects. Working code is shown at https://godbolt.org/z/7jME79EE9 , also here:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>

struct InnerType {
    std::byte value;
    InnerType() {}
    InnerType(std::byte v) : value(v) {}
};
static_assert(sizeof(InnerType) == sizeof(std::byte));

template <class T> class AllocatorExternalBufferT {
    T* const _buffer;
    const size_t _size;
public:
    typedef T value_type;

    constexpr AllocatorExternalBufferT() = delete;
    
    constexpr AllocatorExternalBufferT(T* buf, size_t size) : _buffer(buf), _size(size) {}

    [[nodiscard]] T* allocate(std::size_t n) {
        if (n > _size / sizeof(T)) {
            throw std::bad_array_new_length();
        }
        return _buffer;
    }

    void deallocate(T*, std::size_t) noexcept {}

};

template <class T, class U> bool operator==(const AllocatorExternalBufferT <T>&, const AllocatorExternalBufferT <U>&) { return true; }
template <class T, class U> bool operator!=(const AllocatorExternalBufferT <T>&, const AllocatorExternalBufferT <U>&) { return false; }

typedef std::vector<InnerType, AllocatorExternalBufferT<InnerType>> BufferDataVector;
typedef std::vector<std::byte, AllocatorExternalBufferT<std::byte>> InterfaceVector;

static void report(const InterfaceVector& vec) {
    std::cout << "size=" << vec.size()  << " capacity=" << vec.capacity() << " ";
    for(const auto& el : vec) {
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(el) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() {
    InnerType buffer4allocator[16] ;
    BufferDataVector v((AllocatorExternalBufferT<InnerType>(buffer4allocator, sizeof(buffer4allocator)))); // double parenthesis here for "most vexing parse" nonsense
    v.resize(sizeof(buffer4allocator));
    std::cout << "memory area kept intact after resizing vector:\n";
    report(*reinterpret_cast<InterfaceVector*>(&v));    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do this. Not in a nice safe way but it's certainly possible.

All you need to do is create a fake `std::vector` that has the same ABI (memory layout) as `std::vector`. Then set it's internal pointer to point to your data and `reinterpet_cast` your fake `vector` back to a `std::vector`.

I wouldn't recommend it unless you really need to do it because any time your compiler changes its `std::vector` ABI (field layout basically) it will break. Though to be fair that is very unlikely to happen these days.

Comment: This is just what Dmitryo said actually.